# Flutter set apple status bar color with themeData Brightness

Tags: ios, flutter

I am new to flutter and want to set my apple status bar to a dark theme (That the text is white). In my main I import a separate file with the themes. This is what I got now in themes.dart:

```
AppThemeData _theme = AppThemeData(
    theme: ThemeData(
      brightness: Brightness.dark, //This gives the error "Unhandled Exception: Bad state: No element"
      cardTheme: CardTheme(
        elevation: 1,
      ),
      primarySwatch: Colors.green,
      backgroundColor: Colors.grey[400],
      visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
    ),
    mainScreenBackgroundGradientColors: [Colors.green[700], Colors.green[300]],
    chartThemeData: ChartThemeData(
      lineColor: Colors.yellow[600],
      lineAreaColor: Colors.yellow[100],
      loadingColor: Colors.yellow,
    ),
    deviceChipColor: Colors.green[300],
    infoIconColor: Colors.grey[600]);
```

I came across this [Comment](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/57668#issuecomment-631768800)  and tried that, but that didn't work because context did not exists.

All help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me in the end:

```
ThemeData(
      appBarTheme: AppBarTheme(brightness: Brightness.dark),
    ),
```